SwiftUI keep background stationary as view is dragged
I have implemented a sample video editing timeline using SwiftUI and am facing issues. So I am breaking up the problem in chunks and posting issue each as a separate question.
In the code below, I have a simple timeline using an HStack comprising of a left spacer, right spacer(represented as simple black color) and a trimmer UI in the middle. The trimmer resizes as the left and right handles are dragged. The left and right spacers also adjust in width as the trimmer handles are dragged.
Problem: I want to keep the background thumbnails (implemented currently as simple Rectangles filled in different colors) in the trimmer stationary as the trimmer resizes. Currently they move along as the trimmer resizes as seen in the gif below. How do I fix it?

import SwiftUI

struct SampleTimeline: View {
    
    let viewWidth:CGFloat = 340 //Width of HStack container for Timeline
   
    @State var frameWidth:CGFloat = 280 //Width of trimmer
    
    var minWidth: CGFloat {
        2*chevronWidth + 10
    } //min Width of trimmer
    
    @State private var leftViewWidth:CGFloat = 20
    @State private var rightViewWidth:CGFloat = 20
    
    var chevronWidth:CGFloat {
        return 24
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing:0) {
            Color.black
                .frame(width: leftViewWidth)
                .frame(height: 70)
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
            
                Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.left")
                    .frame(width: chevronWidth, height: 70)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .onChanged({ value in
                                leftViewWidth = max(leftViewWidth + value.translation.width, 0)
                                
                                if leftViewWidth > viewWidth - minWidth - rightViewWidth {
                                    leftViewWidth = viewWidth - minWidth - rightViewWidth
                                }
                                   
                                frameWidth = max(viewWidth - leftViewWidth - rightViewWidth, minWidth)
                                
                            })
                            .onEnded { value in
                               
                            }
                    )
        
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.right")
                    .frame(width: chevronWidth, height: 70)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .onChanged({ value in
                                rightViewWidth = max(rightViewWidth - value.translation.width, 0)
                                
                                if rightViewWidth > viewWidth - minWidth - leftViewWidth {
                                    rightViewWidth = viewWidth - minWidth - leftViewWidth
                                }
                                
                                frameWidth = max(viewWidth - leftViewWidth - rightViewWidth, minWidth)
                            })
                            .onEnded { value in
                              
                            }
                    )
                 
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.title3.weight(.semibold))
          
            .background {
                
                HStack(spacing:0) {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 60)
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.cyan)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 60)
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.orange)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 60)
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.brown)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 60)
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.purple)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 60)
                }
                
            }
            .frame(width: frameWidth)
            .clipped()
            
            Color.black
                .frame(width: rightViewWidth)
                .frame(height: 70)
        }
        .frame(width: viewWidth, alignment: .leading)
    }
}

#Preview {
    SampleTimeline()
}

Update: I have managed to solve problem as follows, but I still feel it is kinda workaround(as I have set an offset to the thumbnails view). Please post a better and accurate solution if you think there is any (such as by using masking that also reduces the frame width of the trimmer at the same time).

import SwiftUI

struct SampleTimeline: View {
    
    let viewWidth:CGFloat = 340 //Width of HStack container for Timeline
   
    @State var frameWidth:CGFloat = 280 //Width of trimmer
    
    var minWidth: CGFloat {
        2*chevronWidth + 10
    } //min Width of trimmer
    
    @State private var leftViewWidth:CGFloat = 20
    @State private var rightViewWidth:CGFloat = 20
    @GestureState private var leftEndPanned = false
    @GestureState private var rightEndPanned = false
    
    var chevronWidth:CGFloat {
        return 24
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing:0) {
            Color.clear
                .frame(width: leftViewWidth)
                .frame(height: 70)
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
            
                Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.left")
                    .frame(width: chevronWidth, height: 70)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .updating($leftEndPanned, body: { _, state, _ in
                                state = true
                            })
                            .onChanged({ value in
                                leftViewWidth = max(leftViewWidth + value.translation.width, 0)
                                
                                if leftViewWidth > viewWidth - minWidth - rightViewWidth {
                                    leftViewWidth = viewWidth - minWidth - rightViewWidth
                                }
                                   
                                frameWidth = max(viewWidth - leftViewWidth - rightViewWidth, minWidth)
                                
                            })
                            .onEnded { value in
                               
                            }
                    )
        
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.right")
                    .frame(width: chevronWidth, height: 70)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .updating($rightEndPanned, body: { _, state, _ in
                                state = true
                            })
                            .onChanged({ value in
                                rightViewWidth = max(rightViewWidth - value.translation.width, 0)
                                
                                if rightViewWidth > viewWidth - minWidth - leftViewWidth {
                                    rightViewWidth = viewWidth - minWidth - leftViewWidth
                                }
                                
                                frameWidth = max(viewWidth - leftViewWidth - rightViewWidth, minWidth)
                            })
                            .onEnded { value in
                              
                            }
                    )
                 
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.title3.weight(.semibold))
            .background {
                
                HStack(spacing:0) {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 60)
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.cyan)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 60)
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.orange)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 60)
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.brown)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 60)
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.purple)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 60)
                }
                .frame(width: viewWidth - leftViewWidth - rightViewWidth, alignment: .leading)
                .offset(x: -leftViewWidth)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .clipped()
                
            }
            
            
            Color.clear
                .frame(width: rightViewWidth)
                .frame(height: 70)
        }
        .frame(width: viewWidth, alignment: .leading)
    }
}

#Preview {
    SampleTimeline()
}



Currently, the colors are shown in the background of the nested HStack. However, this HStack is moving, depending on the size of leftViewWidth. So although you are setting a smaller frame size on the background, you are not compensating for the stack's position.
I would suggest using a different approach. Instead of trying to clip the background, just leave it unchanged and apply a .mask to control which part of it should be visible.

Unlike a clip shape, a mask can be padded. So you can apply the same adjustment to the mask as is being used for the trimmers.
This way, there is no need to compute the visible width. However, if you need to know the visible width for your video editing purposes, you can use a computed property to deliver it. The updated example below includes this computed property, but commented out.

You previously accepted another answer for dragging the trimmers which used GestureState variables to track the drag position (it was my answer). The example in the question is doing it a different way. The version below is based on the same solution as I provided before. I would suggest, this is a simpler way to do it.
struct SampleTimeline: View {
    let viewWidth: CGFloat = 340 //Width of HStack container for Timeline
    let chevronWidth: CGFloat = 24
    let minWidth: CGFloat = 10

    @State private var leftOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var rightOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @GestureState private var leftDragOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @GestureState private var rightDragOffset: CGFloat = 0

    private func leftAdjustment(dragOffset: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let maxAdjustment = viewWidth - rightOffset - (2 * chevronWidth) - minWidth
        return max(0, min(leftOffset + dragOffset, maxAdjustment))
    }

    private func rightAdjustment(dragOffset: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let maxAdjustment = viewWidth - leftOffset - (2 * chevronWidth) - minWidth
        return max(0, min(rightOffset - dragOffset, maxAdjustment))
    }

//    private var frameWidth: CGFloat {
//        viewWidth
//        - (2 * chevronWidth)
//        - leftAdjustment(dragOffset: leftDragOffset)
//        - rightAdjustment(dragOffset: rightDragOffset)
//    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {

            Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.left")
                .frame(width: chevronWidth, height: 70)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .offset(x: leftAdjustment(dragOffset: leftDragOffset))
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .updating($leftDragOffset) { value, state, trans in
                            state = value.translation.width
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            leftOffset = leftAdjustment(dragOffset: value.translation.width)
                        }
                )

            Spacer()

            Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.right")
                .frame(width: chevronWidth, height: 70)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .offset(x: -rightAdjustment(dragOffset: rightDragOffset))
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .updating($rightDragOffset) { value, state, trans in
                            state = value.translation.width
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            rightOffset = rightAdjustment(dragOffset: value.translation.width)
                        }
                )

        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .font(.title3.weight(.semibold))
        .background {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Color.red
                Color.cyan
                Color.orange
                Color.brown
                Color.purple
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            .padding(.horizontal, chevronWidth)
            .background(.background)
            .mask {
                Rectangle()
                    .padding(.leading, leftAdjustment(dragOffset: leftDragOffset))
                    .padding(.trailing, rightAdjustment(dragOffset: rightDragOffset))
            }
        }
        .frame(width: viewWidth)
        .background(.black)
    }
}



Thanks for answering. I am getting a better hold on SwiftUI through these answers and experimenting with other approaches. Although I have accepted your answer, I see you have omitted the left and right views that were part of timeline HStack. In reality, these views would be spacers that would be present on the borders of timeline. They would accommodate shrinking and expansion of timeline. I would need to have a frameWidth applied to this trimmer view as there would be multiple trimmers on the timeline. The neighboring trimmer would shift as the edge of this trimmer is dragged.

In short, this solution keeps width of trimmer fixed. This would give issues when you have multiple videos(trimmers) on the timeline serially one after the other. As I trim one of those videos, I would want the left and the right videos embedded in the HStack move left/right. But that can not happen unless I change frameWidth. Or may be I need to adopt a different approach for the timeline than a plain HStack?

@DeepakSharma Thanks for accepting the answer. The solution provided here was for the question as posed. If you have difficulty adopting it because there are other constraints that weren't mentioned in the question then I would suggest raising a new question, if necessary. However, I would expect that the approach shown here should be usable, even when you have multiple trimmers. Exactly how multiple trimmers should interact with each other would need to be clearly defined.

@BenzyNeed Actually I introduced left and right views to simplify the timeline, otherwise the question unnecessarily gets more complex. Fixing this issue will let me move forward with the more complex timeline where there could be any number of trimmers(videos) embedded in an HStack, which would inturn be embedded in a ScrollView.
